# React.JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router, nullpointerexception

```
interface Props {
  activity: Activity;
  cancelSelectActivity: () => void;
}

export default function ActivityDetails({
  activity,
  cancelSelectActivity,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <Card fluid>
      <Image src={`/assets/categoryImages/${activity.category}.jpg`} />
    </Card>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtCGj.png)

I don't quite understand why null is coming, I wonder if it's related to the react property or did I make a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: Add console before rendering category to check if value is coming or not.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says

> Cannot read property 'category' of undefined.

This means that `activity` (which you're trying to access in the `Image` component) is actually `undefined`.

Accessing the property of an undefined object will give an error.

Where you use the `ActivityDetails` component, check what you're passing as props in the `activity` attribute.

```
<ActivityDetails activity=??? />
```

It could be that you're passing an incorrect `Activity` there itself.